# How to handle "()" in column name so that index can be set on that column using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to set Index on my data frame Iris on a particular column name using Pandas. The column name contains brackets `"(in cm)"` and it is throwing error.How to ensure that column name is taken as it is along with brackets and index is also set on it

I am new to python and learning it for Machine Learning course

The sample code is

```
Iris.set_index(["Sepal Length (in cm)"], inplace = True)
```

My expected result should be that index should be set on the column name. For example the index name of that column should be:

```
"Sepal Length (in cm)"
```

Comment: What is `print (Iris.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: use `Iris.columns= df.columns.str.strip()` and then try setting the index.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (setting `"Sepal Length (in cm)"` as the index works). Please include the complete error message.

Comment: This is working for me as well. Please provide the error message you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: My bad I was trying on python 2.7 that was creating the trouble, once I updated to pandas 3.6 it started working. Thank you all for the response and help